# FTRL optimizer in tensorflow seems not work well

Tags: tensorflow, distributed, logistic-regression

Tried to training LR model on a large scale dataset via tensorflow with FTRL optimizer for a ctr task. tensorflow/sklearn auc and training/evaluation auc are OK. But performance in product is not good. I've tried to lower down the distributed level, but question can't be totally resolved. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found at least two reasons:

First is the underlying implementation is not exactly the same as the original paper. I don't know why they do this, explanation needed.

Second, the gradients used in updating weights are batch gradient, which means update the ps weights once per batch(very trivial in a modern distributed system but not suitable for the scenario in original paper), in a summary it does not utilize the training data record-wise. Personally the second is the key point.

Comment: two differences I obeserved: 1)the beta parameter is implemented by the initialization of accumulator;2)the lambda 2 part is multiplied with a constant 2.  The first difference can be seen as kind of like the difference between 1+x^0.5 and (1+x)^0.5 and its impact needed further experiment.

Comment: can you provide some insight into the non record-wise training ?

Comment: you can use tf.gradients api for small dataset to see the gradient used in the optimizer. And you can refer automatic differentiation, which is the way tf calculate its gradient

Comment: In addition, i am working on a distributed wide model. And in my case, the batch size seems to have a huge impact on the convergence.

Comment: sorry for the delay reply, got a sick leave. I'm also working on a distributed WDL work, personally the official example is not good as expected. Not sure if totally caused by the gradient issue.